# iOSでチェックボックスの実装

Tags: ios, storyboard

出来ればStoryboard上でcheckboxを配置したいのですが、見当たりません。
皆さんはiOSでcheckboxを作る時はどうしていますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIControlStateに対応した画像とtouchに対応してselectの切り替えを実装して作りました。
デフォルトで置いといて欲しいですね

```
[_checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(onCheckboxClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


-(void)onCheckboxClick:(UIButton*)button{
    _updateCheckbox.selected = !_updateCheckbox.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以前UIButtonで実装しました。
ON/OFFに合わせて

```
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XXX.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

で背景画像を変更します。
画像を作らないといけませんが。。

Comment: やはりけっこう手作りしないといけない感じみたいですね。

Answer (score 1):

githubで探すといくつかでてきますね。

- https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox
- https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperCheckbox

自前で作らずこれらを使うのも良いと思います。
個人的にはiOS標準のUIではチェックボックスと同等の機能は、UISwitchで実現できるので、UISwitchを使います。クライアントから要望があったときも交渉してUISwitchで押します。

もしくは設定画面の場合、UITableViewを使うことが多いと思いますが、UITableViewCellを選択した時にaccessoryTypeにUITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmarkをセットするなどして対応します。

Answer (score 1):

自分はこのビデオを参考に作りました
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajlkFFPxW_c

かなり応用が効く方法なので、いろいろなところで使っています（この動画はUIButtonga
ベースですが、UIButtonじゃなくても可能です）

参考になればと思います

Answer (score 0):

正攻法なら、

1. UITableViewを作成し、貼り付ける。
2. UITableViewCellのAccesoryTypeをCheckmarkとする。

こうなるんでしょうが、この目的のためだけに、テーブルビューを作るのは、コストが悪すぎます。さらに、チェックマークが、行頭でなく行末に付きますしね。
お役に立てなそうで、すみません。